# r for loop cor.test function

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a general problem about the R loops in general:
Could someone explain me the error of this?

```
for (i in seq(length=2:ncol(df))) { z <- cor.test(df$SEASON, df[,i], method="spearman");z}
```

easily I would like to use the cor.test(x,y) function between the col called SEASON with all the col of my data frame "df".
Moreover I want that after this calculation, R prints me the results "z".

Comment: Looking at the output of `seq(length=2:5)` should give you an idea. Study `help("seq")`.

Comment: Also, try `print(z)`.

Comment: At a glance (but I could be wrong) I think that the `for` part should be just `( i in 1:ncol(df) )`

Comment: thanks for the replies.. I tried with ( i in 1:ncol(df) ) too.. but it doesn't change anything.. print(z) gives me only one of the correlation results not all..

Comment: Ok I reached the results looking to help("seq")
the right answer is : (i in seq(length.out=2:ncol(df))) even if I don't get it why it should be different from ( i in 2:ncol(df) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't really need a `for()` loop.  You can use the `apply()` function to get the correlation of `SEASON` with all of the other columns of the data frame `df`.

```
# some fake data
n <- 20
df <- data.frame(SEASON=runif(n), A=runif(n), B=runif(n), C=runif(n))

# print the correlation
apply(df[, -1], 2, cor.test, df$SEASON, method="spearman")
```

Second, you are not using the `seq()` function properly.  The `length.out` argument of `seq()` is the "**desired length of the sequence**".  You keep supplying the `length.out` argument with a vector, instead of the scalar (a vector of length one) it is expecting.  That is why you get a warning message when you submit something like, `seq(length.out=2:ncol(df))`.  The function just uses the first element, so the result is the same (without a warning message) as for `seq(length.out=2)`.  If you wanted to use `seq()` to give you the desired result, you would use `seq(from=2, to=ncol(df))`.  This is fine, but I think it simpler and cleaner to simply use `2:ncol(df)` as previous posters suggest.

If you really wanted to use a for loop, this should do the trick:

```
for(i in 2:ncol(df)) cor.test(df$SEASON, df[, i], method="spearman")
```

Comment: Using out <- apply(df[, -1], 2, cor.test, df$SEASON, method="spearman").
What I should do if I want to create a table with the name of the col and the p-value resulted form the apply function?

for example:
>outer(colnames(df[13]),out$AF12$p.value,paste,sep=" ")
"AF12 0.00096268872425193"
#where AF12 is the name of col 13.

this applied for all the out data...

Comment: `sapply(out, "[[", "p.value")`