# In R, use loop (or while or for) to perfom correlation tests between variables measured at two different times

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop, tidyverse

I've tried to adapt this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680497/r-for-loop-cor-test-function) here but it is not working.

Let's say I have this ds

```
ds <- data.frame(ige_1 = c(0,1,2,3),
                 ige_2 = c(0,1,2,3),
                 ige_3 = c(0,1,2,3),
                 ige_1_copy = c(1,2,3,4),
                 ige_2_copy = c(1,2,3,4),
                 ige_3_copy = rep(c(1,2,3,4),100))
```

`copy` means that this variable was measure in another day. My interest it To perform correlations specifically between these variables. Therefore, I can do that:

```
cor(ds$ige_1, ds$ige_1_copy)
cor(ds$ige_2, ds$ige_2_copy)
cor(ds$ige_3, ds$ige_3_copy)
```

However, I would like to make this easier, but my loop isn't working.

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  cor(ds$ige_[[i]], ds_ige_[[i]]_copy, use = "complete.obs")
}
```

Any suggestions? R base or R tidyverse would be appreciated.

Full code

```
ds <- data.frame(ige_1 = c(0,1,2,3),
                 ige_2 = c(0,1,2,3),
                 ige_3 = c(0,1,2,3),
                 ige_1_copy = c(1,2,3,4),
                 ige_2_copy = c(1,2,3,4),
                 ige_3_copy = rep(c(1,2,3,4),100))

cor(ds$ige_1, ds$ige_1_copy)
cor(ds$ige_2, ds$ige_2_copy)

for (i in 1:4) {
  cor(ds$ige_[[i]], ds_ige_[[i]]_copy, use = "complete.obs")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
ds <- data.frame(ige_1 = c(0,1,2,3),
             ige_2 = c(0,1,2,3),
             ige_3 = c(0,1,2,3),
             ige_1_copy = c(1,2,3,4),
             ige_2_copy = c(1,2,3,4),
             ige_3_copy = rep(c(1,2,3,4),100))

cor_var <- numeric()
for (i in 1:3) {
    cor_var[i] <- cor(ds[[paste("ige",i, sep = "_")]],
                      ds[[paste("ige",i,"copy", sep = "_")]], 
                      use = "complete.obs")
}

cor_var
```

You can also use "print" inside the for-loop instead of storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do `cor(ds)` to get all combinations:

```
ds <- data.frame(ige_1 = c(0,1,2,3),
                 ige_2 = c(0,1,2,3),
                 ige_3 = c(0,1,2,3),
                 ige_1_copy = c(1,2,3,4),
                 ige_2_copy = c(1,2,3,4),
                 ige_3_copy = rep(c(1,2,3,4),100))



cor(ds)
```

Result:

```
           ige_1 ige_2 ige_3 ige_1_copy ige_2_copy ige_3_copy
ige_1          1     1     1          1          1          1
ige_2          1     1     1          1          1          1
ige_3          1     1     1          1          1          1
ige_1_copy     1     1     1          1          1          1
ige_2_copy     1     1     1          1          1          1
ige_3_copy     1     1     1          1          1          1
```

Comment: Thanks, but this output returns some unwanted correlation (such as ige_1 with ige_2).

Comment: Yes, but you did not specify that you *only* want the correlations of interest. If you e.g. use the correlations only for manual inspection, than this method is much cleaner and leaves less room for errors than a loop. But if you need them programatically it is not suited directly of course, that's true.

Comment: You're right. I'll edit the question to make it clear. Thank you